# BASH execute multiple commands which are separated by commas

Tags: bash, while-loop, sleep

I'm trying to execute a remote file line by line:

```
curl -sL 'http://remote.com/api/'$1'' | while read NAME
    do
        $($NAME) &
done
```

The remote file is like:

```
sleep 10; wget -O/opt/store/11.xml http://remote.com/api/11
sleep 10; wget -O/opt/store/12.xml http://remote.com/api/12
sleep 10; wget -O/opt/store/13.xml http://remote.com/api/13
sleep 10; wget -O/opt/store/14.xml http://remote.com/api/14
```

I would like to execute every line, but I'm getting an error like:

```
Try `sleep --help' for more information.
sleep: invalid option -- 'O'
```

So sleep is getting the parm `-O...`

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: hm now im getting: ./x.sh: line 3: sleep 10; wget -O/opt/store/12.xml http://remote.com/api/12: No such file or directory

Answer (score 2):

You can use this if **you can trust** that there will be no malicious command in remote file:

```
while read -r line; do
   bash -c "$line"
done < <(curl -sL "http://remote.com/api/$1")
```

Comment: Why not just `bash <(curl -sL "http://remote.com/api/$1")` or `curl -sL "http://remote.com/api/$1" | bash -s`?

Comment: Rightly said, that can be done and avoid the loop here unless OP wants to add some logging etc after each line.